# JQuery returned data from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in JQuery. I have managed to return data to JQuery from php script but now I get to see the message  `<!--Separate connection with sessions -->` when I show the returned message from php script to the user and I only want to display my message to the user using alert().

1. Can someone explain what is that meaning?
2. How to avoid it to be shown to the alert box?

PHP code:

```
<?php
    include "initialize.php";
    if(empty($_POST) === false){
        global $con;
        $message = "";
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        if(isSubscribed($email) === false){
            $message = "Thank you for subscribing to our latest updates";
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES('".$email ."')");
        }
        else{
            $message = "You already subscribed.";
        }
        echo $message;
    }
?>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#frms').on('submit', function (e) {
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if (!validateEmail(email)) {
            alert('Error: Make sure you provided a valid email address');
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'initialize/subscribe.php',
                data: $('#frms').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `what is that meaning` - what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--Separate connection with sessions -->
```

This is an HTML comment, and it probably means when you call the PHP script from your jQuery, that HTML is also added somewhere to the response.

i.e. Your PHP "page" is not only echoing your message; it is echoing that HTML as well.

A quick fix is to kill the PHP script immediately after you echo your message, to prevent any other output from being returned to the jQuery.

```
echo $message;
die;   // Add this
```

This will terminate the script after you echo your message, and not allow any other output to be generated.

If you still see the HTML after adding `die`, it probably means the HTML is added before you echo your message. In which case it might be in `initialize.php` and you would have to prevent that other script from echoing anything as well.

Comment: You just need to find `<!--Separate connection with sessions -->` it's somewhere in your project.

Comment: Thanks BadHorsie, I found out that this output `<!--Separate connection with sessions -->` was being generated on this script `initialize.php`

Comment: @MCi Yes I said that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

return data like this :

$returnArr=array();
  returnArr['message']=$message;

echo json_encode(returnArr);

exit;

and at client side use this code 
alert(data.message);

Comment: I did try that code and is now giving me this message `undefined`

Comment: This what i get  `<!--Separate connection with sessions --> {"message":"You already subscribed."}` when i output data `alert(data)` only

Comment: use this:  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( obj.message );

Comment: Thanks for your effort. your help lead me to find the solution.